# Numpy financial calculating saving plan

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I want to save $1.000.000. How much do I need to save monthly with yearly interest rate of 4% for 5 years? Is there simple numpy financial function to calculate this, or do I need to do it "manually"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The financial functions in numpy itself have been deprecated; you can use [numpy-financial](https://pypi.org/project/numpy-financial/) for this purpose instead.

For your specific question:

```
>>> npf.pmt(0.04/12, 12*5, 0, 1000000, when='end')

-15083.18872193264
```